# Which social login should I use, Google OAuth2 or Google+?

Tags: login, google, authentication

Google supports 4 ways to "sign in with google"

- OAuth
- OAuth2
- Google+
- Google Apps

I want a generic "sign in with google", I'm not doing anything app-specific, so the last one is out.

Presumably OAuth2 is preferable to OAuth and maybe OAuth will become deprecated, so OAuth is out.

What's the difference in the user's experience or in API capability between OAuth2 and Google+?

Comment: You will likely find StackExchange a better place for this question.

Comment: @tim.baker do you mean Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes I do :) Gets a little confusing sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're tying yourself into Google for a social login, **you should use Google+**.

OAuth and OAuth2 are deprecated and will no longer be supported in the future.  Google Apps basically uses Google+ sign in now as far as I'm aware, as every Google account can be used for Google+ sign in even if the user doesn't have a Google+ account.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use OAuth , You can use google+ Sign in . http://janrain.com/product/social-login/  . Go through the URL .These guys provide the best service